# Messing with hand-edited kernel config

Tags: linux-kernel

Some of my coworkers edit the kernel configs of our products manually. The comment or uncomment the options and manually put the 'y' or 'm'. Is it safe for me to load such configurations to menuconfig and friends? What can go wrong?

Comment: I've never seen menuconfig or other similar tools break after hand-editing config files; if you do spot something break, file a bug report. :)

Comment: You could have posted that as an answer so that I can "Accept" it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's safe as long as you run `make oldconfig` or `make menuconfig`, etc. afterwards. "make" takes care of dependencies and activates as needed modules that have been mistakenly disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can hand-edit the kernel configs in the config file. "make" takes care of any dependencies.